# What LifeStyle should ISession have in a Azure Worker Role?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, azure, castle-windsor

I'm building a Worker Role in Windows Azure for computing data and updating various APIs.

What `LifeStyle` should my `NHhibernate` session have for optimal performance?

(I'm using `Castle Windsor` with `NHibernate`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't load too many objects in a session, also sessions shouldn't live for long periods, usually they work better as small unit of work.

I'm not sure how is your code, but you can just configure the SessionFactory as singleton, let windsor inject it, and start a session on your code.